# Universal method for adding fragment, how to implement it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create method for fragment's adding, that i will be able to use many times, but i've faced some error.
This is my method:

```
// global variable
fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

> ```
> private <T> void findFragmentByTagAndAdd(String fragmentTag, Class<?> cls, T t){
>     Fragment fragm = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
>     if (fragm == null) {
>         fragm = cls.newInstance(t);
>         fragManager.beginTransaction()
>                 .add(R.id.host_fragment_container, fragm)
>                 .commit();
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> Where `T t` is some data (for example some model class) that must be passed to setArguments of fragment's newInstance method

I get next error :

```
    cannot be applied to given types;
                    fragm = cls.newInstance(t);
                               ^   required: no arguments   
found: T#1   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: What is the `T t` parameter for ? Is is a fragment constructor parameter ?

Comment: T t is some data (for example some model class) that must be passed to setArguments of fragment's newInstance method. It will passed to bundle in newInstance method

Comment: But in your sample you call `Class.newInstance()` and not `Fragment.newInstance()`, you should check Farhan Rahman Arnob solution.

Comment: Yep, you're right, i have to cast it, but it won't help. I've already found decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
fragm = cls.newInstance(t);
```

with something like:

```
Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(t.getClass());
fragm = (Fragment) constructor.newInstance(t);
```

Comment: In this case i get an error:
'error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Fragment
            fragm = constructor.newInstance(t);'

Answer (score 1):

**Look at findFragmentByTagAndAdd method's Parameter *Class cls*, no use of this and it will be easy for you.**

**Do in this way:**

*Add interface like this.*

```
interface IYourDesireClass<T>{
   T newInstance();
}
```

*Implement this to your desired class.*

```
class YourDesireClass implements IYourDesireClass<YourDesireClass>
```

**And restructure method like this**

```
private <T extends IYourDesireClass> void findFragmentByTagAndAdd(String fragmentTag, T t){
    Fragment fragm = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (fragm == null) {
        fragm = t.newInstance();
        fragManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.host_fragment_container, fragm)
                .commit();
    } 
}
```

**One more thing, try to avoid reflection. [Reflection has a negative effect on performance.](https://plumbr.io/blog/java/six-java-features-to-stay-away-from)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void findFragmentByTagAndAdd(Fragment fragment, T t){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(fragment != null){
        fragment.setArguments(t)
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
      }
}
```

You can pass your data through setArguments()

Refer to this link as well:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i need. You're proposing concrete example with concrete fragment. But i need to create method that can add any fragment provided in argument. My fragManager it is a fragmentManager that i already defined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6271180/benoit)'s answer my method finally starts working and it looks like this:

```
    private <T> void findFragmentByTagAndAdd(String fragmentTag, Class<?> cls, T data){ 
    Fragment fragm = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    if (fragm == null) {
        try{
            Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(data.getClass());
            fragm = (Fragment) constructor.newInstance(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        fragManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.host_fragment_container, fragm, fragmentTag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And then i just call it:

```
findFragmentByTagAndAdd(DogsListFragment.DOGS_TAG, DogsListFragment.class, (Owner)owner);
```

Thanks all who was involved in my question, guys!

This method will be useful if you use multi-pane UI and have to add/replace fragments many times in your host-activity